# Netbeans replace in projects regular expression

Tags: regex, netbeans

I am trying to replace the following content which is in several files using `Edit-> Replace in Projects`.

```
<head>
   ...
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
   ...
</head>
```

Basically I want to match anything within  and the head tags also. I tried this snippet on regexpal.com and it works fine (at least in javascript).

```
<head>(.|\s)*</head>
```

I thought maybe I need to escape the `<>` brackets but that didn't work either. I'm not really sure why `<head>*</head>` didn't match anything under the non-regex search. I am able to match for searching `<head>` so it's definitely searching the correct files.

Netbeans is version 6.9

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(<head>(.|[\r\n])*</head>)
```

Answer (score 0):

5 years old question, but in case someone comes with the same doubt, I got it with:

```
(?<=&lt;head&gt;\r\n)(.|\n|\r)*(?=&lt;/head&gt;)
```

`(?<=&lt;head&gt;\r\n)`- Look behind for `<head>` AND carriage return (otherwise the replace will mess the formatting)

`(.|\n|\r)` - Matches anything between `<head>` and `</head>`

`(?=</head>)` - Look ahead for `</head>` tag